# Server "connection" implication in a web page load

Tags: connection

I'm talking with a "tech guy" and he's asserting that:
if a user open a web page (for example www.mysite.com/mywebpage.php) and leaves the browser open, the connection with the server remains open until the browser close.

Is this true? Or once the page is loaded the server has finished its work?
(the page is a simple HTML page)

Does this depend on Apache config somehow?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't quite work like that.  HTTP connections have a keep-alive option (defaults to on in later versions of the HTTP protocol), which leaves a session open between the client and server for more data requests.  However, both servers and clients will eventually close that connection and some clients may not even set it.

[More info here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection).

You'll see (from that article) that most clients close their persistent connections after a reasonably short duration, and most web servers close them on an even shorter timeout.